# Passing ArrayList as generics parameter in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList<String>` and I need to pass each String in this ArrayList, as parameter of this function:

```
protected Void myFunction(String... params)
```

NOTE: I can't modify `myFunction`

Comment: The parameter is a `String` array , why do you need to pass as individual `String` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transform it to an array with the [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method :

```
myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 2):

1.To pass it as individual String:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String element:list){
  myFunction(element);
}
```

2.To pass an Array of String.

```
myFunction(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the arraylist into array of String and then pass it

```
instanceName.myFunction(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
```

**NOTE**: You don't have to change the signature of your method.

CHECK THIS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()

Comment: You'll have Object[], not String[]. There's another toArray method that has a more accurate return type.

Comment: Parameterless `toArray()` returns `Object[]` only! You need to invoke `toArray(new String[0])` (or better, supply the correct size)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your ArrayList in parameter and then iterate on the arraylist with a foreach inside your method:

```
protected void myFunction(ArrayList<String> myArrayList){
    for(String myParam : myArrayList){
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```